# Can I remote install a free iPhone app using WiFi to iPhones connected to it?

Tags: iphone, xcode, installation, wifi

I am trying to install an iPhone app to all users connected to my WiFi. Is there a way by which I can achieve that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming, it is about installing apps.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't. You can install app only from iTunes; Apple is very strict in that.

Comment: Can you automate the installation of an app from the Apple Store directly onto iPhones connected to your WIFI network?

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not possible.You can only install the app through iTunes or through Xcode if you have its source code.

Comment: through XCode? Can you explain this in detail please?

Answer (score 0):

Nope; you can only install a new app through the app store, or through iTunes.

EDIT: if you've jailbroken your iPhone, it looks like you can use [Installer.app](http://www.appsafari.com/maps/825/installerapp/) to install packages over wifi. Check that link for instructions on jailbreaking, and on linking to various package sources. If you set up your server as a source, you could then have users install from that server.